# Overloading functions taking auto&&

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, auto

I'm able to overload functions with generic template arguments, such as this example:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename... Args>
void
f(Args...)
{
  std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
}

class S {};

template<typename... Args>
void
f(const S&, Args...)
{
  std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
}

int
main()
{
  f(1, 2, 3);
  f(S{}, 2);
}
```

The output is

```
void f(Args...) [Args = <int, int, int>]
void f(const S &, Args...) [Args = <int>]
```

That is, the overload is called when the first argument is of type `S`, which is what I expected.

If I change this to use `auto&&...` instead of templates, the behavior is no longer what I expected:

```
#include <iostream>

void
f(auto&&...)
{
  std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
}

class S {};

void
f(const S&, auto&&...)
{
  std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
}

int
main()
{
  f(1, 2, 3);
  f(S{}, 2);
}
```

Here, the output is

```
void f(auto &&...) [auto:1 = <int, int, int>]
void f(auto &&...) [auto:1 = <S, int>]
```

That is, the overload is not called – the first function is called in both cases.

This leads to two questions:

1. What are the rules for functions taking `auto&&...` with respect to overloading?
2. What is the correct way to write the overloaded function so that the behavior is the same as the template version?

Comment: Remove the `&&` from `auto &&`. - live - https://godbolt.org/z/KxPMa7qE9

Comment: the code is not equivalent, f(Args&&...) would be needed in the first version

Comment: You are passing `S` as a prvalue, making `S &&` a better match than `const S &`.

Comment: This may make answering your questions easier. Do you know what a forwarding reference is?  Your two programs would behave the same if both used forwarding references or if neither used forwarding references.